# Auto refresh of the cart

Tags: ajax, magento-1.9

When I have two items in the cart, I open a second tab where it also shows two items

and now if I add another item then the cart(second tab) will show a total of 3 items.

Now The question is, if I go back to the first tab, how can I see three items in the cart without refreshing the tab.

Auto refresh of the cart: When I have two items in the cart, I open a second tab where it also shows two items

and now if I add another item then the cart(second tab) will show a total of 3 items.

Now The question is, if I go back to the first tab, how can I see three items in the cart without refreshing the tab.

Comment: Try polling to server or use local storage and poll to that storage after specific time interval.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are two ways: 1. Call ajax requests to server every approx.

2 seconds, this depends on your server configuration. If server can handle frequent ajax requests.

Using LocalStorage object, there will be no frequent ajax requests and server will be free for other requests. You have to call for/while loop for any change in qty. This is security risk but depends on what you store in LocalStorage. Never store sensitive data. Please ref. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp